# Container div out of parent div

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure out why my `project-img-text-container` is falling outside of its parent div `project-image-container` and `project-img-main`. I added in `project-image-container` to combat this issue, but it did nothing and I am drawing a blank. I have both containers set to relative, so not sure why `project-img-text-container` is falling out when it is set to `absolute`.

Anyone see why?

```css
#project-img-main {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
#project-image-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
#project-img-window {
 max-height: 700px;
 /*background: rgba(0,0,0,0);*/
 width: 100%;
}
#project-img-text-container {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 position: absolute;
 width: 33%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 60%;
 z-index: 99;
}
#project-img-text {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 2em;

}
```

```html
 <div id="project-img-main">
  <div id="project-image-container"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/eslich/images/projects/project-main3.jpg" id="project-img-window" alt="Demolition and Wrecking Projects">
   <div id="project-img-text-container">
    <div id="project-img-text">Test</div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#project-img-text-container {
    top:0;
}
```

When setting something as position absolute, you need to specify it's position within the document or containing element.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: Other way the element will keep the "initial" position taken by the flow of the document.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to use a defined height, `position: relative` alone can not hold the element within. Since `project-img-text-container` `position` property value is `absolute`, you need to add `top:0` to its block of CSS.

```css
#project-img-main {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
#project-image-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
#project-img-window {
 max-height: 700px;
 /*background: rgba(0,0,0,0);*/
 width: 100%;
}
#project-img-text-container {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 position: absolute;
 width: 33%;
 height: 100%;
     top: 0; /* This has to be 0 to bring it up to the top */
 left: 60%;
 z-index: 99;
}
#project-img-text {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 2em;

}
```

```html
<div id="project-img-main">
  <div id="project-image-container"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/eslich/images/projects/project-main3.jpg" id="project-img-window" alt="Demolition and Wrecking Projects">
   <div id="project-img-text-container">
    <div id="project-img-text">Test</div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
img{
  position: absolute;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rittamdebnath/hwj28zm3/